# How can I stop Internet Explorer from creating new instances?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, internet-explorer

Is it a way to stop IE to create a new instance everytime it encounters a popup window? I'm debugging two Silverlight applications at the same time. The first one creates new popup window with the second one. Debugging works fine in FireFox because it does not create a separate process. But IE creates new instance and of course Visual Studio is not attached to the new instance of IE.

Comment: I don't know if there is, but just to get you going, you could always run a second instance of devenv and attach to the new process with ctrl+alt+p.

Comment: Thanks JP. Like I said for the time being I'm using FireFox but I just get used to have FireFox as my default browser opened all the time and IE for development. So far it worked out really nicely, but now I have this app which creates new app, hence the problem.

Comment: Or change the app to not create popups. They are nasty and most users dislike them anyway. Now seriously, I know GDB on Linux can automatically attach to child processes with the "follow-fork-mode". maybe Visual Studio has a similar option.

Comment: Haven't seen it such option in VS. I mean it automatically attaches to the first instance of IE and to the server - I don't expect it to attach itself to even more processes.

Re popups: yes, you are right they are nasty. But the first application is like an authoring tool for the second one. I mean you are designing second application using the first one and it acts like a preview. So I guess this behaviour is used only by a very limited set of power users.

BTW: Silverlight by default overrides browser's popup blocker - I'm not sure if this is such a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE? If you are using 7+ can you change the popup setting to "Open in a new tab" instead of a new window? (Tools -> Options -> Tab Settings).

Comment: IE8, and funny thing: I've changed this option and new pages are being opened in tabs, but still as separate processes. Frankly speaking I have no idea how guys from Redmond did this. I mean separate processes and one UI - this is tricky, but this is how it works. Oh, and tabs color changes from blue to green (I guess to indicate that they are securely handled by separate instances).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you open a new window in IE (either by using Javascript, or selecting "File > New Window"), it should *not* start a new process. A new process is only started when you actually run the executable again (from Windows explorer, for instance).

Since MSIE is so closely related to Windows Explorer though, I wonder if it's somehow tied to one of the Windows Explorer settings. Try going to any explorer window, select Tools > Options, select the "View" tab, and make sure that "Launch folder windows in a separate process" isn't checked, that may be it.

Another possibility is in MSIE, Tools > Options, select the "Advanced" tab check "Reuse Windows for launching shortcuts," though I doubt this would be it.

Comment: Both options have been already set to correct values: Launch folder windows... unchecked, and Reuse Windows for... checked.